# How to work with different versions of Qt on the same machine?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, conflicting-libraries

I have problems since I installed both Qt 4.8.4 and Qt 5.1 on my computer.

When only Qt 4.8.4 was present, everything was fine.

When I added Qt 5.1, this one is working properly, but Qt 4.8.4 gives me these linker errors:

```
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lQtGuid
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lQtCored
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug/BuildSystemTest3.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
09:21:00: The process "C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project BuildSystemTest3 (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
```

I could replicate the problem on a trivial test project (the one created by QtCreator by default), with this pro file:

```
QT += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = BuildSystemTest3
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS += mainwindow.h
```

The two Qt versions are installed in two separate directories: C:\Qt\4.8.4 and C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0
MinGW is a link to either MinGW_4.6.2 (for Qt4) or MinGW_4.7.2 (for Qt5).

Can different versions of Qt coexist on the same computer? How?

Comment: What does Tools > Options... > Build & Run > Qt Versions show?

Comment: There are the paths of both Qt4 and Qt5's qmake executables under the 'Manual' branch. Auto-detect is empty.

Comment: You may delete Qt5 entry from there. No point having it in Qt 4.8.4. And check if your project settings have reflected that change.

Comment: @DavyJones: I removed every reference to Qt5 from the project options, both from "Qt Versions" and "Compilers". In "Kits", the default is set to Qt 4.8.4, pointing to the correct MinGW. I get the same linker errors...

Comment: You project settings and the vars there? Are they also updated? If not, you might have to point to your 4.8 installation manually.

Comment: You mean the settings in "Options > Build & Run"? They all point to Qt 4.8.4 now. I created a new test project from scratch after changing the settings, and it behaves in the same way.

Comment: From the logs generated during the build, all references are to Qt 4.8.4 and MinGW 4.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a problem with the `QTDIR` environment variable pointing to the 5.1 installation.

You could create two batch files like this (might have to add full path to qtcreator.exe):

*qtcreator484.bat*:

```
set QTDIR=C:\Qt\4.8.4
start qtcreator.exe
```

*qtcreator510.bat*:

```
set QTDIR=C:\Qt\5.1.0
start qtcreator.exe
```

and place them e.g. on your desktop. Then always start QtCreator via the batch files for the configuration you want.

Side node: There are sometimes problems when having two QtCreator instances up at the same time, e.g. the second instance cannot write to the console.

Comment: It is possible to set a custom build environment in QtCreator settings. Also QtCreator automatically sets QTDIR variable. http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.5/creator-build-settings.html#build-environment

Comment: Nifty, never knew that. I've used the batch-file approach for Visual Studio successfully, where changing QTDIR was sufficient